# gdb: a binary compiled with -g and stripped versus a binary compiled without -g

Tags: gcc, elf

I tried to debug an embedded application on a target with gdb. Therefore, gdb running on the host requires a binary with debug symbols, i.e. a binary compiled with -g. On the target a stripped copy of the binary is sufficient. On the target I tried to use a binary compiled without -g instead of a stripped copy, but it didn't work.

GNU strip discards all symbols from object files (compiled with -g). So, isn't it equal to a binary compiled without -g? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: -g also turns off optimisations that are on by default, so it is not equivalent to stripping the executable.

Comment: @n.m. You are mistaken: for GCC , the `-g` flag does *not* affect optimization *at all*.

Comment: @EmployedRussian you're right, must be another myth carried over from old bad many-proprietary-unixes days.

Answer (score 0):

> On the host I tried to use a binary compiled without -g instead of a stripped copy, but it didn't work.

You got this reversed: you need stripped binary on the target, and full-debug binary on the host.

`gdbserver` does *not* need (or use) debug info produced by `-g`, `gdb` does.

It is best to not compile twice, but rather compile once with `-g`, then:

```
cp a.out a.out.stripped
strip -g a.out.stripped
```

and keep both full-debug and stripped binary together.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, target and host in the description were swapped. I've corrected my question. Thanks!

Comment: Back to my question: Would it work to use strip without -g in order to remove ALL symbols? If so, I assume that it is not recommended to compile twice since we don't really know in detail what the compiler does.

Comment: @xaverius Fully stripping all symbols should also work, but there are bugs in `strip`, such as https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11786